# How to remove duplicates rows in Bigquery using the DELETE statement?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with millions of rows. I have duplicates in those rows (X rows having the exact same values in all the columns) and would like to remove them without creating a temporary table (because of some constraints), but instead only use the `DELETE` statement to remove the problematic rows.

The combination of the following columns can be used to identify duplicates: `Timestamp`, `column_1`, `column_2`, `column_3`, `column_4`

I'm currently using the following query to delete the duplicated rows but I do not think that it's working as expected (It might not be deleting all duplicates):

```
DELETE FROM BIGQUERY_TABLE t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM (
    SELECT
      Timestamp,
      column_1,
      column_2,
      column_3,
      column_4,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY Timestamp, column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4
        ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
      ) AS rn
    FROM
      BIGQUERY_TABLE
    WHERE Timestamp > 1709424000000 AND Timestamp < 1709510400000
  ) d
  WHERE
    t.Timestamp = d.Timestamp AND
    t.column_1= d.column_1 AND
    t.column_2= d.column_2 AND
    t.column_3 = d.column_3 AND
    t.column_4 = d.column_4 AND
    d.rn > 1
)
AND t.Timestamp > 1709424000000 AND t.Timestamp < 1709510400000;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach and query are almost correct with only a few mistakes.

Below is the revised version of your query that may work:

```
DELETE FROM BIGQUERY_TABLE
WHERE STRUCT(Timestamp, column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4) IN (
  SELECT AS STRUCT Timestamp, column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4
  FROM (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY Timestamp, column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4 
        ORDER BY Timestamp
      ) as rn
    FROM BIGQUERY_TABLE
    WHERE Timestamp > 1709424000000 AND Timestamp < 1709510400000
  )
  WHERE rn > 1
) AND Timestamp > 1709424000000 AND Timestamp < 1709510400000;
```

Comment: Thank you! The only issue I see with this query is that it processes the entire table instead of using the table partitioning (Which is based on the timestamp), is there any way to only process data between the two abovementioned timestamps?
I've tried adding the Timestamp filter in the line below but it doesn't seem to help:
`WHERE rn > 1 AND Timestamp > 1709424000000 AND Timestamp < 1709510400000`

Comment: I got it. Just updated my answer for that. The same timestamp conditions are repeated in the outer `DELETE` query to ensure that only rows within this range are considered for deletion. Check if that works.

Comment: Thanks again. One last question which is outside of the scope of the original question, how do I check for the percentage of duplicates per day once I have run your query?

Comment: Hi, that would be a different scenario and may be a bit more complicated to calculate. You may wanna post a separate question to get a better help.